# How to call scope methods defined in the link function from a directive's controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

[Here's a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KYPCA1f3DabFC0eHNgxG?p=preview) - I want "To be replaced" to be replaced by "Replacement".

My problem is as follows. I have two directives, myTabs and myPane In myTabs' `link` function, I add a method to its isolate scope called `setValue`. Now, I want myPane to be able to set the value, so I added a method `setValue` to myTabs' controller that basically calls the scope's method. However, because the controller function is run before the link function, the scope's method can't be accessed.

For the complete code, see the Plunker, but here are the relevant parts:

Directives:

```
angular.module('docsTabsExample', [])
.directive('myTabs', function() {
  return {
    transclude: true,
    scope: {},
    controller: function($scope) {
      this.setValue = $scope.setValue;
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.value = 'To be replaced';
      scope.setValue = function(value){
        scope.value = value;
      };
    },
    templateUrl: 'my-tabs.html'
  };
})
.directive('myPane', function() {
  return {
    require: '^myTabs',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
      tabsCtrl.setValue('Replacement');
    }
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="docsTabsExample">
<my-tabs>
<my-pane>
   One pane
</my-pane>
<my-pane title="World">
   Another pane
</my-pane>
</my-tabs>
</body>
```

When [run](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/KYPCA1f3DabFC0eHNgxG/), in the console you can see `Error: tabsCtrl.setValue is not a function`.

Now, just to make sure I'm not headed too much in the wrong direction already, I should describe my actual problem. I'm writing a directive that `require`s ngModel, *and* that has a nested directive. Since I can only access ngModel's controller in the link function, the setValue() method can only be added to the scope there, but I need the controller to expose the API to the nested directive, which is why I'm trying to do `this.setValue = $scope.setValue;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really just need to let the directives controller manage access to $scope.

When the controller is created it will have the same scope that the directive does, so you could rework the controller code to look like this:

```
controller: function($scope) {

 //Snip...

 this.setValue = function(value){
   $scope.value = value;
 };
}
```

With that logic moved to the controller, you can safely remove the scope function from your directive. **However, there is an order of operation problem that you need to solve.**

By default, a `link: function(){}` is a Post Linking function, which will execute ***AFTER*** all the child directives have been linked. You can solve this by moving the logic to a Pre Linking function because that executes ***BEFORE*** the child directives have been linked.

```
link: {
  pre: function(scope, element, attrs){
   scope.value = 'To be replaced';
   //No need for function here
  }
}
```

Now your nested directives can simply execute the method on the controller, which will in turn set the appropriate value on scope. Nothing there needs to change.

Here is a Plunker with those changes: http://plnkr.co/edit/ERf24t93rm1pmr8avyV1?p=preview

### UPDATE

Ok, so here is a complete example to show how you can use `ngModel` from within a child directive in order to affect the actual bound model. You can see that changes are updated in both the `<input>` bound to `progressValue` as well as the actual custom control.

And in case you want to play with this on your own, here is a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/zdzm0l4THlCDTvdP4ne3?p=preview

```js
(function() {

  var template = '<div>' +
    '<div ng-transclude></div>' +
    '<div class="progress">' +
    '<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped"' +
    ' role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0"' + 
    ' aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">' +
    '<span></span>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';

  function ParentWithModelDirective() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: 'ngModel',
      template: template,
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,
      scope: {},
      link: {
        pre: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
          var progressBar = elem.find('div').find('div'),
            label = progressBar.find('span');

          ngModel.$parsers.push(function(viewValue) {
            var numValue = 0;

            if (angular.isString(viewValue)) {
              viewValue = viewValue.replace('%', '');
            }

            numValue = parseInt(viewValue);

            return isNaN(numValue) ? 0 : numValue;
          });

          ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
            return ngModel.$isEmpty(value) ? 'N/A' : value.toString() + '%';
          });

          ngModel.$render = function() {
            progressBar.css('width', ngModel.$viewValue);
            progressBar.attr('aria-valuenow', 
                             ngModel.$isEmpty(ngModel.$modelValue) ? 
                             0 : 
                             ngModel.$modelValue);
            label.text(ngModel.$viewValue);
          };
        }
      }
    };
  }

  function ChildOfParentDirective() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: '^ngModel',
      template: "<button type='button' class='btn btn-success'>Complete</button>",
      scope: {},
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {

        function listener() {
          ngModel.$setViewValue('100%', 'click');
          ngModel.$render();
        }

        elem.on('click', listener);
      }
    };
  }

  function AnotherChildOfParentDirective() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: '^ngModel',
      template: "<button type='button' class='btn btn-warning'>Reset</button>",
      scope: {},
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
        function listener() {
          ngModel.$setViewValue('0%', 'click');
          ngModel.$render();
        }

        elem.on('click', listener);
      }
    };
  }

  angular.module('sample-app', [])
    .directive('parentWithModel', ParentWithModelDirective)
    .directive('childOfParent', ChildOfParentDirective)
    .directive('anotherChildOfParent', AnotherChildOfParentDirective)

}());
```

```html
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container" ng-app='sample-app' ng-init="progressValue = 30">
  <div class="masthead">
    <h3 class="text-muted">Sample App
        </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Progress Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="progressValue" />
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <parent-with-model ng-model="progressValue">
        <h1><code>progressValue = {{progressValue}}</code></h1>
        <child-of-parent></child-of-parent>
        <another-child-of-parent></another-child-of-parent>
        <br />
        <br />
      </parent-with-model>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Site footer -->
  <div class="footer">
    <p>by <a href="http://www.technofattie.com">Techno Fattie</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean, but note my final paragraph: the method setValue() is in the link function because it needs access to the ngModel controller - not because it needs to manage access to $scope. Thus, moving that logic to the controller is not really an option, unless I can access the ngModel controller from there...

Comment: @Vincent - You can require ngModel as a parent dependency on your child controller. `^ngModel` In which case it would be a moot point.

Comment: Do you mean in addition to having it as a dependency on the parent controller? And if so, would they refer to the same model/do I need to do something to get that to be the case?

I really want at least the parent to require ndModel, as the slider as a whole represents the value, and there could be other child directives as well that also need access to the model.

Comment: @Vincent - I've updated the answer with a complete example that hopefully shows how you can use `ngModel` from within a child directive to do what you want.

Comment: You really went above and beyond, thank you very much! Indeed, when I `require` ngModel in the parent directive, and `^ngModel` in the child directive, they refer to the same controller. With that, I've now been able to make it work with a very clean solution - thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need an `ngModel` on `myTabs`?  If you don't you can just move the `setValue` function straight up to the controller to solve your problem.

Comment: I do need it. I guess the naming is confusing as I based my Plunker on one from the Angular docs which used tabs as an example, but my directive is a slider with a nested handle directive. The slider's value is the ngModel.